C# DotNetZip ошибка метода Save()
В коде ошибок явных нет, но при запуске в движке Unity появляется ошибка, что нету ссылки на объект и указывает именно на метод сохранения архива Save()
Код:
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "92646742";
    zip.AddFile(path);
    zip.Save(new FileStream(pathZip, FileMode.Create));
}

path - путь к добавляемому файлу с его полным именем
pathZip - путь с полным именем архива, который создаётся(путь к данному архиву)

ну так покажите, где и как объявляете эти переменные, показ кода лучше любого самого красивовго рассказа.

Этот вопрос похож на: Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Если ты напишешь так:
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    var file = FileMode.Create;
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathZip, file))
    {
        zip.Password = "92646742";
        zip.AddFile(path);
        zip.Save(stream);
    }
}

То можно будет говорить, не о каких-то там строчка, а о конкретных методах.
Я подозревая, что exection проиходит в конструкторе FileStream, а не в методе "ZipFile.Save()", а у тебя возникает NullReferenceException потому что file == null, что так-же можно легко проверить.
А вообще текст этих... как их там... "ошибок"! надо писать! По ним тоже можно узнать, где именно и в чём ошибка.
FileStream кстате тоже IDisposable и требует .Dispose() или using.
